# RecyclerView scrolling issue (Child items far away from each other)

Tags: android, view, scroll

Goodd day.I have simple recycler view with simplest dummy datas for test purpose,thus i have an weird issue to which the google did not find any solution or even an issue at all.On first launch the view is all good but as soon as i start to scrool,the child items are being as far from each other as no one can image...Really very and very far.But the issue is that the actual child items layout parameters are correct,only issue is that i dont know why RecyclerView decides to have each item heaps far away from each other.Please can you give me an help?Posting full code of my RecyclerView.

The view for recyclerView

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ink.activities.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Adapter.

```
public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<FeedModel> feedList;
    private Context mContext;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, content;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedTitle);
            content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedContent);
        }
    }


    public FeedAdapter(List<FeedModel> feedList, Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        this.feedList = feedList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.feed_single_view, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FeedModel feedModel = feedList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(feedModel.getTitle());
        holder.content.setText(feedModel.getContent());

//        animate(holder);
    }


    public void animate(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final Animation animAnticipateOvershoot = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.bounce_interpolator);
        viewHolder.itemView.setAnimation(animAnticipateOvershoot);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return feedList.size();
    }
}
```

I guess you won`t need holder as no view initiated with it.
The single child item view of RecyclerView adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feedTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/appFont"
                android:text="loading...."
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feedContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/feedTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The initiation of actual parameters.

```
 mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new FeedAdapter(mFeedModelArrayList, this);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(500);
        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(500);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
```

This code is as simple as it can get and it is important to mention that i am initiation all this inside the default `NAVIGATION DRAWER ACTIVITY` of android studio (the default templae inside `content_main layout`).So plaese can you give me any hint about the issue?

Comment: There's a change in the latest version of RecyclerView, try setting the child view height to wrap_parent at the top level. The change causes views to match_parent where old versions forced wrap_content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

on your child item views. As of [Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html#recyclerview):

> The RecyclerView widget provides an advanced and flexible base for creating lists and grids as well as supporting animations. This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.
>
> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of your item views: **previously ignored layout parameters (such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.**

Change your `layout_height` to `wrap_content` if you only want your items to be as large as needed. `match_parent` means they will be as large as the screen.

Comment: Perfect!!!! I just was playing around and wanted to put my own answer as solution as i found that recycler view is not like listView or any other one,so the ROOT layout MUST have wrap_content height! perfect!Thank you very much SOLVED!